# What must I do to make my methods awaitable?

Tags: c#, windows-8, async-await, windows-store-apps

How can I roll my own async awaitable methods?

I see that writing an async method is easy as pie in some cases:

```
private async Task TestGeo()
{
    Geolocator geo = new Geolocator();
    Geoposition pos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
    double dLat = pos.Coordinate.Latitude;
    double dLong = pos.Coordinate.Latitude;
}
```

...but sadly also see that not just any method can be made async willy-nilly, though; to wit: this doesn't work:

```
private async Task TestAsyncAwait()
{
    int i = await TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5);
}
```

...it stops me with the compile error, "Cannot await int"; a hint at design time similarly tells me, "type 'int' is not awaitable"

I also tried this with the same results:

```
    Task<int> i = await TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5);
```

What must I do to make my methods awaitable?

### UPDATE

As Linebacker and S. Cleary indicated (any relation to that cat who used to be on KNBR?), this works:

```
int i = await Task.Run(() => TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5));
```

...that is to say, it *compiles* -- but it never "moves."

At runtime, it tells me I should "await" the CALL to TestAsyncAwait(), but if I do that, it doesn't compile at all...

Comment: `int i  = await Task.Run(() => TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5));`

Comment: I recommend you read [TAP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957)

Comment: So Lambdas are not just de rigeur, but obligatory now? I've viewed them, at least up to now, as clever-clever tricks.

Comment: Are you sure you *want* to make this awaitable?

Comment: No, I'm just experimenting - I want to know how to make methods awaitable so that I can "do it until the cows come home" or "without even thinking (much) about it" when I need to.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You only *need* to return an awaitable. `Task`/`Task<TResult>` is a common choice; `Task`s can be created using `Task.Run` (to execute code on a background thread) or `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (to wrap an asynchronous event).

Read the [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 18):

Your method

```
private async Task TestAsyncAwait()
{
    int i = await TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5);
}
```

should be written like this

```
private async Task TestAsyncAwait()
{
    Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() =>
    {
        return TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5);
    });
    t.Start();
    await t;
}
```

If you need to return the int, replace the Task type:

```
private async Task<int> TestAsyncAwait()
{
    Task<int> t = new Task<int>(() =>
    {
        return TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5);
    });
    t.Start();
    return await t;
}
```

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 3):

```
var something = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 0);
something.Wait();
int number = something.Result;
```

Comment: Downvoted because the OP is clearly trying to do this asynchronously

Comment: Thanks to aaronburro for adding a downvote explanation.  This is too rare.

Comment: Rare and useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either consume the awaited return or return `Task<Type of await call>`

1. ```
   private async Task<Geoposition> TestGeo()
   {
       Geolocator geo = new Geolocator();
       return await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
   }
   ```
2. ```
   private async Task<int> TestAsyncAwait()
   {
       return await TaSLs_Classes.TASLsUtils.GetZoomSettingForDistance(5);
   }
   ```

Comment: The question is about #2, and for #2, the error says "Type 'int' is not awaitable"